# The tag removal is [complete]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I ran into a question today tagged with [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complete) which (at the time of writing this) has no wiki description, no approved synonyms, 31 watchers, and [256 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complete?tab=newest&page=6&pagesize=50).

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No - it might mean finishing a task? or a "complete set" of something? or used as a synonym for [auto-complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto-complete)? or a command or event named "complete"? ...just to name a few. It's one of the most vague tags I've seen.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

I suppose this could be considered on-topic depending on what the definition is determined to be?

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No - it seems most questions attempt to define what "complete" means within the title or body, and so the tag seems superfluous.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Simply, no. It could mean a number of different things, even within the same question.

Comment: The questions that are tagged with [[tag:complete]] look like they have *very* little in common; there's a range of languages and technologies being tagged along side it. If someone is watching that tag I doubt it's going to often be related to the skill set they have.

Comment: There seems to be a considerable number of [r] questions tagged with this. Apparently there's a `complete` function in that language that is often referenced. Now, I don't think we should have tags for functions (it's just too granular, but if we must, the tags should have the language included), but apparently there's a demand.

Comment: Based on currently visible questions, possible the first question with that tag is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/146093/1) in 2008 about "complete graph"

Comment: Lets [complete] a burnination for once. Seems very ambiguous and could also refer to the complete function in R.

Comment: why not add an r and give a proper guidance

Comment: @nbk nobody reads guidance, and the tag can refer to even more things.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Given, only 37 out of the 265 questions are tagged [[tag:complete]] + [[tag:r]].

Comment: I [complete]ly agree with burninating this tag.

Comment: I just pulled some numbers; across all posts tagged with [[tag:complete]], there are ***376*** unique tags being used on posts alongside "complete," +1 more if you include the closed post from today ([Here's the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=complete)). The most used also appears to be [[tag:jquery]], beating [[tag:r]] by 1.

Comment: @zcoop98 - we should probably either create a [complete-function] or [r-complete] tag (not necessarily the names listed), move the questions there and then burn the tag. P.s. Count +1 to the burnination request.

Comment: Remove half the tag

Comment: Change the title to Let’s [complete]ly remove this! ;)

Comment: There is also [tag:completion] tag. Could be nominated for removal too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complete) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

As the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) function complete is too granular to warrant a tag, the tag simply needs removal where the question is still fine.

Questions actually about [autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autocomplete) can be tagged as such if not already:

> Autocomplete is a UI feature provided by applications, where the program predicts a word or phrase that the user wants to type without the user actually typing it completely.

For autocomplete functionality in an IDE such as [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) or [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse), please include the appropriate IDE tag as well.

## Progress:

The [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complete) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=complete),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcomplete%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcomplete%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcomplete%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcomplete%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of burnination](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=406885)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complete) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complete) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complete) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: I added the guidance for [tag:autocomplete] since that seems fairly well defined and already has 15,774 questions.

Comment: Huh, there's a tag [tag:code-complete]: *"Code Complete" is a software development book, written by Steve McConnell and published in 1993 by Microsoft Press.*  23 questions.  Should a tag like that exist?

Comment: @dbc nah, autocomplete is a tag we actually want to also remove.

Answer (score 79):

I'm 100% on board with this.

Out of curiosity, I decided to see if I could find out how many unique tags are used on posts tagged with [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complete), using SEDE.

I succeeded, and came up with [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=complete) that got me the number: **376** unique tags, used across the 256 total tagged posts. This sounded potentially high, but in itself may not be much of a problem.

The problem, you see, is that the *overwhelming* majority of those tags are used 3 times or less. 272 of them are used just one single time, and only ***36*** total are used *more than* 3 times. The topical breadth of these 36 is mildly hilarious; it includes, in no particular order: [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), and [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift).

If that's not a clear testament to a tag being *un*clear, I don't know what is. There's nothing to be salvaged here, burn away.

<del>It might be worth doing something about the 3 questions tagged with only "complete", though, which are:</del>

- <del>[Checking for NSURL load done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857170/checking-for-nsurl-load-done)</del>
- <del>[Why won't my bubble sort sort my array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57641206/why-wont-my-bubble-sort-sort-my-array-of-objects)</del>
- <del>[Auto Complete is not working on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64341240/auto-complete-is-not-working-on-android-studio)</del>

*(These questions have since been retagged more appropriately.)*

Comment: All 3 of the questions with only [complete] look like they need another one. The first one needs to specify which language it's in (looks like c, but I could be wrong); the second one should have [bubble-sort]; and the third should have [java] and [android]. Even more evidence [complete] is [complete]ly useless.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 The first one is Objective-C. It actually had the tag originally, but someone removed it for some reason.

Comment: The android studio one would be deleted without intervention. The second is a java question.

Comment: Looking through the [tag:complete] questions also tagged [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complete+c%23), [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complete+vb.net) and [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complete+.net), it's just a grab bag of random stuff, from questions about Visual Studio auto-complete to `IDataflowBlock.Complete` to task completion to general questions about updating forms when something completes.  No value added by the tag there as there are already sufficiently relevant tags.

Comment: Please guys, don't replace complete with a equally bad tag: autocomplete

Comment: `I'm 100% on board with this.` -- Missed opportunity to be [complete]ly on board.

Answer (score 12):

I agree with this. This is so ambiguous that it could mean just about anything, and many of the possible meanings aren't even programming-related.

A few of the topics represented here:

- Waiting for observables in Angular
- Filling in missing values in R. There is apparently an R function named `complete`. We could create a more specific tag for this if it's needed I guess, but someone who knows R better than I do would have to weigh in on that point.
- Details about a call stack generated in Java
- Completing a form with Selenium
- Complete binary trees
- How to finish a particular program

Given that there's little consistency in how this is being used, this tag appears to add little value. It won't help people find questions to answer, it won't help people find information that they're looking for, and it won't help with analytics.

Comment: In C and C++ there's the concepts of complete type vs incomplete type. There is a tag for incomplete type but not for complete. There's also Turing complete, auto complete... lots of wildly diverse topics.

Comment: @Lundin lets go like Jack the Ripper, one tag at a time :)