# Is this tag beyond [repair]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [repair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repair) tag on Stack Overflow's main site has no tag excerpt or description, and the ~170 questions tagged with it are a mish-mash of unrelated questions ranging from handling auto-repair of MSIs, repairing MySQL tables (borderline offtopic) and even repairing laptop keyboards (clearly offtopic).

From a quick read through the questions, it seems like it's a meta-tag at best or a honeypot for offtopic questions at worst.

Can we please have it burninated?

Comment: The title should be: "Can we [repair] this tag with fire?" ;)

Comment: @yivi I'd rather prase it as a question instead of a decision (which isn't mine to take), but I like the idea. Edited the title accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: This tag suffers from the [same syndrome](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406885/is-this-tag-completely-useless/406889#406889) as [[tag:complete]]– most tags used in conjunction with it are only used on a single question, and the tag *most* used with it is on <20% of [[tag:repair]] questions. See for yourself using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?tagname=repair).

Comment: @zcoop98 Nice query! If you don't mind I will use it for [another burn request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406928/lets-go-off-script)

Comment: @zcoop98 couldn't agree more. IMHO, by the same logic, they should both be burninated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Please burn. From taking samples, the tag has coalesced on a  meaning that is off-topic. The meaning is "how do I fix this corrupted data".

Since the topic is off-topic, the tag is subject to burnination despite the fact the normal decision ladder would save it.

I did find a couple of on-topic questions for repairing damaged source control repos, but I don't see how that saves the tag as these are on-topic essentially by accident due to using certain programming tools being on topic.

Writing code to automate repair of data corruption would be on-topic, and I have seen a few such questions, but I found no questions of that form tagged with repair.

Burn please, and most questions tagged with repair should go away with it.

Answer (score 9):

Given that a good percentage of questions on Stack Overflow are about fixing something that's broken (e.g. about non-working code), this tag could apply to most Stack Overflow questions. I say we remove it as a Meta tag.